# Asymmetric plane pixels size

Tags: javascript, three.js

i am trying to make a plane in size 600X600 pixels but i just manage to get asymmetric plane as shown at the picture in black: [asymmetric plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6guYN.jpg)

i tried to switch to combined camera and use the orthographic mode like this:

```
signals.windowResize.add( function () {

    if (camera.inPerspectiveMode) {
        camera.cameraP.aspect = container.dom.offsetWidth / container.dom.offsetHeight;
        camera.cameraP.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    else {
        camera.cameraO.left = window.innerWidth / -2;
        camera.cameraO.right = window.innerWidth / 2;
        camera.cameraO.top = window.innerHeight / 2;
        camera.cameraO.bottom = window.innerHeight / -2;
        camera.cameraO.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.setSize(container.dom.offsetWidth, container.dom.offsetHeight);
    render();

} );
```

but it still not working. i also tried to change the pixelRatio without success.
should i change the camera FOV? camera aspect? canvas size? any idea how to solve it? 
thank you, Dan

Comment: Maybe your screen is set to wrong resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the camera aspect is set by the perspective camera, that why it didn't work well, maybe @mr.doob knows why.

solution:

```
    signals.windowResize.add( function () {

    if (camera.inPerspectiveMode) {
        camera.cameraP.aspect = container.dom.offsetWidth / container.dom.offsetHeight;
        camera.cameraP.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    else {
        camera.cameraP.aspect = container.dom.offsetWidth / container.dom.offsetHeight;
        camera.cameraO.updateProjectionMatrix();
        camera.toOrthographic();

    }

    renderer.setSize(container.dom.offsetWidth, container.dom.offsetHeight);
    render();

} );
```